# How to create a RandomAccessStreamReference to access a resource defined in a .rc file?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, resources

Working in "traditional" C++, I would like to embed a ONNX file (for usage with WinML) into a DLL as a resource, adding it to the .rc file: `IDR_NETWORK     ONNX    "network.onnx"`
 That is working fine, I can access the resource using the `FindResource`, `LoadResource`, and `LockResource` functions.

For **loading this file with WinML**, there is a method `LearningModel::LoadFromStream` taking a `winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::RandomAccessStreamReference`as argument. That seems to be the right interface to load the network from something else than a file.

I tried with `winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::RandomAccessStreamReference::CreateFromUri` but I do not see how to create an URI for the embedded resource.

My current workaround is to extract the resource, save to a temporary file and load using `LearningModel::LoadFromFilePath` from the temporary file.

Best would be **some example** code how to directly access the resource.

Alternativly creating a `RandomAccessStreamReference` to access the pointer returned by `LockResource` would help.

Answer (score 1):

The following example (pseudo) code does the trick:

```
        HRSRC hResource = ::FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(iRessourceID), L"ONNX"))
        HGLOBAL hMem = ::LoadResource(hModule, hResource)

        const BYTE* pData = (const BYTE*)::LockResource(hMem);
        const size_t iSize = ::SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);

        using namespace Windows::Storage;
        using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams;

        InMemoryRandomAccessStream modelStream;
        DataWriter writer(modelStream);
        writer.WriteBytes(array_view<const unsigned char>(pData, pData + iSize));
        writer.StoreAsync().get();

        ::FreeResource(hMem);

        modelStream.Seek(0);

        auto modelStreamReference = RandomAccessStreamReference::CreateFromStream(modelStream);
        auto model = LearningModel::LoadFromStream(modelStreamReference);
```

This codes creates a copy of the data, potentially that could be improved.